# Why should use FetchType.LAZY with FetchMode.JOIN instead of FetchType.EAGER?

Tags: hibernate

Why should use `FetchType.LAZY` with `FetchMode.JOIN` instead of `FetchType.EAGER`?.`FetchType.LAZY` with `FetchMode.JOIN` is equal to Eager mode. Is it right?. Why putting `Fetchmode.join` means if any lazyintialization exception occurs then we can add `fetchmode=join` ?. Why can't directly to use `fetchtype.Eager`. So Is there any advantages to use fetchtype and `fetchmode.join()`?.

Answer (score 1):

With small result set data models, **FetchType.EAGER** do not impact greatly on latency and memory footprints with **FetchMode.JOIN**.

For high volume dataset model which requires optimum efficiency depending on technical and environmental factors, **FetchType.LAZY** is more desirable, in that the join table pointer is kept intact - yet actual result set is held on demand.

For example: A house object eagerly joined with dataset keys is cumulatively different from area code object eagerly joined with phone number object, in terms of efficiency and resource utilization.

Where necessary:

- Use **FetchType.EAGER** for small resultset join.
- And use **FetchType.LAZY** for large resulsets join where efficiency is deemed essential.

Answer (score 0):

With fetch="join" on a collection or single-valued association mapping, you will actually avoid the second SELECT (hence making the association or collection non-lazy)

Referenced from

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies

Answer (score 0):

FetchType is more appropriate to be used in entity annotation. Most of time I will suggest you to use `lazy` load.

In this case, if you need to prevent `LazyIntializationException`, you can adhoc request the criteria to load as `eager` by using `FetchMode.JOIN`.

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
    .setFetchMode("mate", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .setFetchMode("kittens", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .list();
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider a class Employee which has List of Salary Sleeps (a join). 1 EMployee has say more than 100 Salary sleeps.

you want to have List of all employees (say 1000). 
Suppose we want to show employee information only (No Salary Sleeps). 
but when we load it with Eager mode even all salary sleeps loaded with all employees. which is overhead on memory.